# Kotlin no longer available in Eclipse Marketplace

Tags: kotlin, eclipse-plugin

Searching for "kotlin" in the Eclipse marketplace  (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/kotlin) yields a single results: MyBatis Generator.

The download site on the Github page (dl.bintray.com) has been shut down a year ago (https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/). The same goes for the nightly build on https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/.

Despite that, the plugin code was updated a few days ago.

Is there a place left where I can download the plugin? Or is IntelliJ now the only IDE which can be used to edit Kotlin code?

Comment: The plug-in had stopped working with the current Eclipse releases because it referenced a plug-in that is not included in Eclipse as standard anymore. Maybe they have just given up rather than fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin no longer available in Eclipse Marketplace :
Hi , as I was also facing this issue so
i did google and find something you can also try .
Link : https://marketplace.eclipse.org/
scroll the page after opening above link then you will find Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse. follow steps and install Katlin plugin in eclipse ide.

Thanking you